# Modifying Adwords Script to pause Ad Group instead of Text Ad

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm looking for some help with an adwords script that I'm currently toying with. The aim is for the script to crawl the URLs in an account, and any pages that have "currently unavailable", the script will pause the ad.

At the moment it does just that - however I'd like it to pause the ad group instead of the actual ad.

Would anyone be able to give me some pointers of where I'm going wrong?

I'm using the following code:

```
var URL_LEVEL = 'Ad'; // or Keyword
var ONLY_ACTIVE = false; // set to false for all ads or keywords
var CAMPAIGN_LABEL = 'Script1'; // set this if you want to only check campaigns with this label
var STRIP_QUERY_STRING = true; // set this to false if the stuff that comes after the question mark is important
var WRAPPED_URLS = false; // set this to true if you use a 3rd party like Marin or Kenshoo for managing you account
// This is the specific text to search for 
// on the page that indicates the item 
// is out of stock.
var OUT_OF_STOCK_TEXT = 'currently unavailable';

function main() {
  var alreadyCheckedUrls = {};
  var iter = buildSelector().get();
  while(iter.hasNext()) {
    var entity = iter.next();
    var url = cleanUrl(entity.getDestinationUrl());
    if(alreadyCheckedUrls[url]) {
      if(alreadyCheckedUrls[url] === 'out of stock') {
        entity.pause();
      } else {
        entity.enable();
      }
    } else {
      var htmlCode;
      try {
        htmlCode = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
      } catch(e) {
        Logger.log('There was an issue checking:'+url+', Skipping.');
        continue;
      }
      if(htmlCode.indexOf(OUT_OF_STOCK_TEXT) >= 0) {
        alreadyCheckedUrls[url] = 'out of stock';
        entity.pause();
      } else {
        alreadyCheckedUrls[url] = 'in stock';
        entity.enable();
      }
    }
    Logger.log('Url: '+url+' is '+alreadyCheckedUrls[url]);
  }
}

function cleanUrl(url) {
  if(WRAPPED_URLS) {
    url = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('http'));
    if(decodeURIComponent(url) !== url) {
      url = decodeURIComponent(url);
    }
  }
  if(STRIP_QUERY_STRING) {
    if(url.indexOf('?')>=0) {
      url = url.split('?')[0];
    }
  }
  if(url.indexOf('{') >= 0) {
    //Let's remove the value track parameters
    url = url.replace(/\{[0-9a-zA-Z]+\}/g,'');
  }
  return url;
}

function buildSelector() {
  var selector = (URL_LEVEL === 'Ad') ? AdWordsApp.ads() : AdWordsApp.keywords();
  selector = selector.withCondition('CampaignStatus != DELETED').withCondition('AdGroupStatus != DELETED');
  if(ONLY_ACTIVE) {
    selector = selector.withCondition('CampaignStatus = ENABLED').withCondition('Status = ENABLED');
    if(URL_LEVEL !== 'Ad') {
      selector = selector.withCondition('AdGroupStatus = ENABLED');
    }
  }
  if(CAMPAIGN_LABEL) {
    var label = AdWordsApp.labels().withCondition("Name = '"+CAMPAIGN_LABEL+"'").get().next();
    var campIter = label.campaigns().get();
    var campaignNames = [];
    while(campIter.hasNext()) {
      campaignNames.push(campIter.next().getName());
    }
    selector = selector.withCondition("CampaignName IN ['"+campaignNames.join("','")+"']");
  }
  return selector;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:
entity.pause()

You would use:
entity.getAdGroup().pause()

Same for the enable().

Answer (score 0):

Also instead of:

```
var url = cleanUrl(entity.getDestinationUrl());
```

Please use:

```
entity.urls().getFinalUrl();
```

because `getDestinationUrl()` has been deprecated.

I hope this will be useful for someone.